# How to generate delivery report fail (bounce) like gmail when I send bulk mail using php?

Tags: php, email

When I send bulk mail to all of my subscribers , how do I detect
successful delivery or bounce? Suppose a few emails on subscriber list
are not valid or do not exist, how we can detect that in php?

Comment: Add a bounce email address to the email header and monitor that email account via a PHP script.

Comment: Please more that leas and leds mailservers are actually sensing the NDR reports.. Spammers use the mails to devide faulty and valid mailaddresses

Comment: This type of report we got on the mail-server but I want to monitor this on my server where we can consider and set a flag on bounced email address.

Comment: You could do as @superphonic suggests and set a bounce address in the mailheader and read that particular mailbox and parse the results. Or you could just parse your mail log for bounces.

Answer (score 0):

if sending read receipts is enabled, is that you need to include a new line at the end of every line:

```
$email_header .= "Disposition-Notification-To: $from\r\n"; 
$email_header .= "X-Confirm-Reading-To: $from\r\n";
```